# Problem in rewriting links with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

I'm using this htaccess file to rewrite links,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ file.php?show=$1
```

But I'm having problem so, when i go to the page I wanted after rewrite like this: http://somesite.com/mypage
It goes to that page successfully, but when you type a slash in the end of the link (http://somesite.com/mypage/) it doesn't open and says 404 error..

Please fix the code so I can enter pages with slashes or without

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)(\/)?$ file.php?show=$1
```

Comment: +1 Small Hint: no real need to escape the slash and making it a catch group (placing in brackets). Replacing `(\/)?` by this `/?` will do the same job.